# Issue with JQuery slider

Tags: jquery, css

I have made a slider using Jquery which functions properly but as soon as it gets to the last slide it does not slide over to the first one, instead it just instantaneously displays the first slide. Also it does not stay on the last slide even for a second.

[JSfiddle for slider](http://jsfiddle.net/ymFQR/5/)

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="header">
            <h3>J-Slider</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="slider">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <img width="750px" height="400px" src="http://cdn.wonderfulengineering.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/space-wallpapers-1.jpg">
                </li>
                <li>
                    <img width="750px" height="400px" src="http://cdn.wonderfulengineering.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/space-wallpapers-13.jpg">
                </li>
                <li>
                    <img width="750px" height="400px" src="http://th08.deviantart.net/fs70/PRE/f/2014/071/5/5/blue_space_by_whendell-d79zabi.jpg">
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    font-family:Gerogia;
    font-size:15px;
}
#container {
    width:930px;
    margin:50px auto 10px auto;
    border-left:#666 solid 3px;
    border-right:#666 solid 3px;
    background:#f5f5f5;
    padding:20px 30px;
}
#header {
    padding:10px 0;
    border-bottom:#ccc solid 1px;
    overflow:hidden;
    text-align:center;
}
h3 {
    font-size: 30px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
}
.slider {
    width: 750px;
    height: 400px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 75px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.slider ul {
    width:8000px;
    list-style-type:none;
}
.slider li {
    float: left;
}
```

JQuery:

```
$('document').ready(function () {
    var width = 750;
    var animationSpeed = 1000;
    var pause = 3000;
    var currentSlide = 1;

    var $slider = $('.slider');
    var $slideContainer = $slider.find('ul');
    var $slides = $slideContainer.find('li');

    setInterval(function () {
        $slideContainer.animate({
            'margin-left': '-=' + width + 'px'
        }, animationSpeed, function () {
            currentSlide++;
            if (currentSlide === $slides.length) {
                currentSlide = 1;
                $slideContainer.css('margin-left', 0);
            }
        });
    }, pause);
});
```

Comment: should it slide automaticly like it does or do you want a click function? do you want the slide to slide back to the first picture or do you want the last picture to fadeout and then the first picture fadesin again? It is hard to help without some more information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/prashantptapase/ymFQR/20/) code. or below code

Maybe your solution.

```
$('document').ready(function () {
var width = 750;
var animationSpeed = 1000;
var pause = 3000;
var currentSlide = 1;

var $slider = $('.slider');
var $slideContainer = $slider.find('ul');
var $slides = $slideContainer.find('li');

setInterval(function () {
    $slideContainer.animate({
        'margin-left': '-=' + width + 'px'
    }, animationSpeed, function () {
        currentSlide++;
        if (currentSlide === $slides.length) {
            currentSlide = 1;
            //$slideContainer.css('margin-left', 0);
            $slideContainer.animate({ 'margin-left': 0  


 }, pause ); 
                }
            });
        }, pause);
    });
```

Comment: Thank you. But is there any way so that the slider stays on the last image for a few seconds(say 2 seconds). As you can see as soon as it reaches last image it immediately slides back to first one. I have tried the delay() function but it messes with the timing of the animation of the first slide.

Comment: @DineshS Please check this link [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/prashantptapase/ymFQR/26/). for 3 rd slide it stop for 3 sec.

Comment: Haha... Now it stops at the last slide for 3 sec. But the transition from second to third slide happens in a second. It should wait 3 secs before going from second to third slide. You see, the delay() function messes up the timing(intervals) of the setInterval() function.

Comment: @DineshS [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ymFQR/28/). This might be correct solution for you.

Answer (score 2):

I changed your code a bit, I put a copy of the first element at the last position, and modified your code a bit

```
$('document').ready(function () {
    var width = 750;
    var animationSpeed = 1000;
    var pause = 3000;
    var currentSlide = 1;

    var $slider = $('.slider');
    var $slideContainer = $slider.find('ul');
    var $slides = $slideContainer.find('li');

    setInterval(function () {
        $slideContainer.animate({
            'margin-left': '-=' + width + 'px'
        }, animationSpeed, function () {
            currentSlide++;
            if (currentSlide >= $slides.length) {
                currentSlide = 1;
                $slideContainer.css('margin-left', 0);
            }
        });
    }, pause);
});
```

Change

```
if (currentSlide === $slides.length)
```

To:

```
if (currentSlide >= $slides.length)
```

An example : [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/StevenLangeraert/ymFQR/23/)

**Update: Issue with image border on the left**

To make it all work I modified your css (put left margin of **UL** to 0px)

```
.slider ul {
    width:8000px;
    list-style-type:none;
    padding-left: 0px
 }
```

Updated jsFiddle : [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/StevenLangeraert/ymFQR/24/)

Answer (score 0):

try changing how and when you increment the slides, and when you reset it back to one.
in your current js, you increment to the last slide, then tell it to go back to one right away

```
$('document').ready(function () {
    var width = 750;
    var animationSpeed = 1000;
    var pause = 3000;
    var currentSlide = 1;

    var $slider = $('.slider');
    var $slideContainer = $slider.find('ul');
    var $slides = $slideContainer.find('li');

    setInterval(function () {
    $slideContainer.animate({
        'margin-left': '-=' + width + 'px'
    }, animationSpeed, function () {
        if (currentSlide === $slides.length) {
            currentSlide = 1;
            $slideContainer.css('margin-left', 0);
        } else {
            currentSlide++; // move this down here
        }
    });
}, pause);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not a pro in Javascript but i think i figured your problem.

When you animate you do currentSlide++, and just after you do the check (currentSlide ==$slides), so you iterate your currentSlide and just after you tell him to change to the first. As said mmseasor just before put it after.

For your not returning back problem is because on the action in the if loop you forgot to animate slideContainer, so it just displays.